# How do I see the value of a DependencyProperty in WinDbg?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, debugging, dependency-properties

Using WinDbg and trying to debug a Silverlight application for memory leaks, I come across properties on my objects that are implemented as a DependencyProperty - and when I dump the object in the debugger (WinDbg) I can see the property - that is, I can see the actual static field.

How do I see the actual value of the property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the value using the GetValue(PropertyName) method on the DependencyObject (which is required for it to have a Dependency Property). Not sure if that works in WinDbg. [Tess Ferrandez mentions one tip with Dependency Properties](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2008/09/16/q-a-reader-emails-about-net-memory-leaks-and-random-questions.aspx) but it doesn't give a true answer.

Comment: Thanks - I guess I'll have to experiment. Looks like I've fallen off the edge of community knowledge with this one :)

Answer (score 6):

This heavily relies on making assumptions about undocumented internals that may vary in other versions, but by way of example here's how to get the value of the Title property of a window in WPF with .NET 4, documented here so I can find it with Google again.

First, find the address of the value of `System.Windows.Window.TitleProperty`:

```
0:000> !name2ee *!System.Windows.Window
...
Module:      54b81000
Assembly:    PresentationFramework.dll
Token:       0200009c
MethodTable: 54f06b54
EEClass:     54ba12bc                          <--- Remember this
Name:        System.Windows.Window
...

0:000> !DumpClass /d 54ba12bc                  <--- EEClass value from above
...
62887fec  40002f1      4cc ...ependencyProperty  0   static 020e724c TitleProperty
...                                                         ^^^^^^^^ Property object address
```

Now, get its `GlobalIndex`, which is the bottom 16 bits of the `_packedData` field:

```
0:000> !DumpObj /d 020e724c                    <--- Property object address from above
...
62a9c190  4001377       20         System.Int32  1 instance   262372 _packedData
...                                                           ^^^^^^ & 0xffff == 228
```

So 228 is the `GlobalIndex`.

Now find the address of the window:

```
0:000> !name2ee *!Your.Window.Class.Name
...
Module:      00122e9c
Assembly:    YourAssembly.exe
Token:       020001fc
MethodTable: 002a4068                          <--- Remember this
EEClass:     00297504
Name:        Your.Window.Class.Name
...

0:000> !dumpheap -mt  002a4068                 <--- Remember this
 Address       MT     Size
020e6b6c 002a4068      456                     <--- If >1 object found, you must pick the right one.
...
```

The window is at 020e6b6c. The value you are looking for is somewhere in its `_effectiveValues` array:

```
0:000> !DumpObj /d 020e6b6c
...
6288e394  4001359       10 ...ctiveValueEntry[]  0 instance 0912e08c _effectiveValues
...                                                         ^^^^^^^^ Array address

0:000> !DumpArray -details 0912e08c
...
[18] 0912e124
    Name:        System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry
    MethodTable: 6288978c
    EEClass:     627bda2c
    Size:        16(0x10) bytes
    File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsBase.dll
    Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
        57bcf568  40013a7        0            System.Object      0     instance     091df9c8     _value
        57bd4798  40013a8        4             System.Int16      1     instance          228     _propertyIndex
        62a9c360  40013a9        6             System.Int16      1     instance           27     _source
...
```

The array is sorted by the values of the `_propertyIndex` fields (except for some empty entries at the end with `_propertyIndex == -1`) so it is not hard to find the entry with `_propertyIndex` 228.

Finally, dump the corresponding `_value` field:

```
0:000> !DumpObj /d 091df9c8
...
57bcf568  40013c0        4        System.Object  0 instance 020f6228 _baseValue
57bcf568  40013c1        8        System.Object  0 instance 091df92c _expressionValue
57bcf568  40013c2        c        System.Object  0 instance 00000000 _animatedValue
57bcf568  40013c3       10        System.Object  0 instance 00000000 _coercedValue
...

0:000> !DumpObj /d 020f6228                  <--- From _baseValue, gives the binding expression
...
Name:        System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression
...

0:000> !DumpObj /d 091df92c                  <--- From _expressionValue, gives the actual value
...
String:      YOUR WINDOW TITLE
...
```

Woo hoo.

Answer (score 1):

For a complete solution, try this step-by-step guide: http://georgelache.blogspot.ro/2012/04/steps-to-get-value-of-dependency.html

The example covers the case of obtaining the title of a window

!CLRStack -a

..

0000000000129270 000006442d6acf50 System.Windows.Window.InternalClose(Boolean, Boolean)

```
PARAMETERS:

    this (0x0000000000129360) = 0x0000000011b59968

    shutdown = <no data>

    ignoreCancel = <no data>

LOCALS:

    <no data>

    <no data>

    <no data>
```

...

0:000> !do **0x0000000011b59968**

Name:        GFW.Controls.View.ShellWindow
MethodTable: 00000644805228b8
EEClass:     0000064480516240
Size:        832(0x340) bytes
...

00000644319b3708  40002d3      998 ...ependencyProperty  0   static **00000000115de6d8** TitleProperty
00000644319be898  4001323       20 ...ctiveValueEntry[]  0 instance **00000000154ff638** _effectiveValues
...

0:000> !do /d **00000000115de6d8**

Name:        System.Windows.DependencyProperty

MethodTable: 00000644319b3708

EEClass:     0000064431857550

Size:        88(0x58) bytes

File:        C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsBase.dll

Fields:

```
          MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
```

00000644784c6960  400133c        8        System.String  0 instance 00000000111f6450 _name

00000644784c82e8  400133d       10          System.Type  0 instance 0000000011024538 _propertyType

00000644784c82e8  400133e       18          System.Type  0 instance 0000000011255ea8 _ownerType

00000644319b12a8  400133f       20 ....PropertyMetadata  0 instance 00000000115de678 _defaultMetadata

00000644319b1088  4001340       28 ...dateValueCallback  0 instance 00000000115de638 _validateValueCallback

00000644319be750  4001341       30 ...ndencyPropertyKey  0 instance 0000000000000000 _readOnlyKey

0000064431c147f8  4001342       40         System.Int32  1 instance           **262462** _packedData

00000644319be408  4001343       48 ....InsertionSortMap  1 instance 00000000115de720 _metadataMap

00000644319b0fc8  4001344       38 ...erceValueCallback  0 instance 0000000000000000 _designerCoerceValueCallback

00000644784c5ab8  400133b      808        System.Object  0   static 000000001102f290 UnsetValue

00000644319bc6c0  4001345      800 ...ty, WindowsBase]]  1   static 0000000021033b88 RegisteredPropertyList

00000644784d1c28  4001346      810 ...ections.Hashtable  0   static 0000000011030aa8 PropertyFromName

00000644784cc848  4001347      5c8         System.Int32  1   static             1290 GlobalIndexCount

00000644784c5ab8  4001348      818        System.Object  0   static 00000000110407e8 Synchronized

00000644784c82e8  4001349      820          System.Type  0   static 0000000011040800 NullableType

GlobalIndex: Get the index of the property: **262462** & 0xFFFF (using Windows Calculator) = 318

!DumpArray -details **00000000154ff638**

[31] 00000000154ff838

```
Name:        System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry

MethodTable: 00000644319b6120

EEClass:     0000064431858c90

Size:        32(0x20) bytes

File:        C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsBase.dll

Fields:

                  MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name

    00000644784c5ab8  400136e        0            System.Object      0     instance     0000000041dd7b88     _value

    00000644784d0930  400136f        8             System.Int16      1     instance                  318     _propertyIndex

    0000064431c149b0  4001370        a             System.Int16      1     instance                   11     _source
```

0:000> !do /d **0000000041dd7b88**

Name:        System.String

MethodTable: 00000644784c6960

EEClass:     000006447804eec8

Size:        108(0x6c) bytes

File:        C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll

String:      My Window Title

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please add a few more precise information if ever the link became dead - ( that happens more often that you think) - that is preferred on SO. Maybe could you sum up the procedure.